# Check existence of a key recursively and append to array of dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I've a dict as follows

```
{
   "key1" : "value1",
   "key2" : "value2",
   "key3" : "value3",
   "key4" : {
       "key5" : "value5"
   }
}
```

If the dict has key1==value1, I'll append the dict into a list.

Suppose key1==value1 is not present in the first key value pair, whereas it is inside nested dict as follows:

```
{
   "key2" : "value2",
   "key3" : "value3",
   "key4" : {
       "key5" : "value5",
       "key1" : "value1",
       "key6" : { 
          "key7" : "value7",
          "key1" : "value1"
       }
   },
   "key8" : { 
       "key9" : "value9",
       "key10" : {
            "key11" : "value11",
            "key12" : "value12",
            "key1" : "value1"
       }
   }
}
```

In the above dict, I've to check first whether there is key1=value1. If not, I've to traverse the nested dict and if it found in the nested dict, I've to append that dict to the list. If the nested dict is also a nested dict but key1=value1 is find in the first key value pair, then no need to check the inner dict(Eg key4 has key1=value1 in the in the first key value pair. Hence no need to check the inner one eventhough key6 has key1=value1).

So finally, I'll have the list as follows.

```
[
   {
       "key5" : "value5",
       "key1" : "value1",
       "key6" : { 
          "key7" : "value7",
          "key1" : "value1"
       }
   },
   {
            "key11" : "value11",
            "key12" : "value12",
            "key1" : "value1"
   }
]
```

How to achieve this?
Note: The depth of the dict may vary

Comment: Do you have "arbitrary" deep dicts or only to a "manageable" limit?

Comment: @syntonym Assuming it to be arbitrary deep..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if a dict contains `key1` and `value1` we will add it to the list and finish.
if not, we will got into all the values in the dict that are `dict` and do the same logic as well

```
l = []
def append_dict(d):
    if d.get("key1") == "value1":
        l.append(d)
        return

    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            append_dict(v) 


append_dict(d)
print l
```

an iterative solution will be adding to queue the dict we would like to check:

```
from Queue import Queue
q = Queue() 
l = []
q.put(d)
while not q.empty():
    d = q.get()
    if d.get("key1") == "value1":
        l.append(d)
        continue
    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            q.put(v) 

print l
```

As @shashank noted, usinq a `stack` instead of a `queue` will also work
it is [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) vs [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) for searching in the dictionary

Comment: Wouldn't `if d[k] == v` be enough? Also it's recursive which may not work for arbitrary deep dicts (because python max recursion depth) but might still be enough.

Comment: as writing the explanation noticed that too. true about recursice, will do it also iterative

Comment: The OP requested recursion

Comment: True, `Stack` vs `Queue` will be `DFS` vs `BFS`

Comment: Good answer. Note: If you want to simulate the LIFO depth-first search ordering, then a Stack should be used instead of a Queue.  Or use a Deque to simulate the *exact* order of a recursive function. A queue will do breadth-first search.

Comment: @MosheCarmeli He used the term in the title to indicate he wants to traverse all "sub dicts", but recursive processing is not compatible with arbitrary deep dicts in python, whereas the iterative solution will work. I don't think he used the term `recursive` technical but to describe his problem.